# controllers, services and unit of work - should I really dispose database context?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Based on this article: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application
**Should I really dispose context?**

For example I have controller with dispose method:

```
public class BlogController : Controller
{        
    private readonly INotesService _notesService;        

    public BlogController(INotesService notesService)
    {
        _notesService = notesService;
    }


    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        _notesService.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

So my controller call dispose method from service:

```
public class NotesService : INotesService
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public NotesService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }


    public void Dispose()
    {
        _unitOfWork.Dispose();
    }
}
```

And service call dispose method from unit of work:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private DatabaseContext context = new DatabaseContext();
    private INotesRepository notesRepository;

    public INotesRepository NotesRepository
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.notesRepository == null)
            {
                this.notesRepository = new NotesRepository(context);
            }
            return notesRepository;
        }
    }

    private bool disposed = false;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                this.context.Dispose();
            }
        }
        this.disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

In each controller I must remember to call Dispose method. What is more, if my controller uses many services I have to remember to call Dispose method on each service in controller method called also Dispose.

So should I really dispose database context? Maybe it isn't necessary.

Answer (score 2):

It's not *strictly* necessary in the sense that the garbage collector will eventually come behind you can clean up after you, but it's still good practice to explicitly dispose of anything you no longer need. The controller is instantiated and destroyed for each request, so if you fail to dispose of the resources you accumulated, then you're effectually leaking memory in the interim period between the controller's teardown and the next GC cycle. If you're fielding a ton of requests, that can potentially bring things to a grinding halt if the memory drain adds up faster than deallocation. Depending on the amount of RAM installed on your server, you also may end up paging to the hard disk at times, which will really kill application performance.

Long and short, just follow best practices and dispose of your resources properly. Then, you don't have to worry about whether or not it will eventually be a problem, as it never will be.

For what it's worth, you can allay some of the shaving-a-yak work in this by utilizing a good dependency injection framework. A DI container will manage the lifetimes of your objects and handle disposing of them appropriately. It's kind of cheating, but since dependency injection is good practice, anyways, you might as well take advantage of it.